# Hash table are collision events independent

Tags: probability, hash-function

Say I have some universal hash table of size $m$ and random input data set of size $n$.
Let's define $I_{i}$ indicator RV as probability that while inserting ith key to the table collision happened.

I want to bound probability that number of collisions is far from its expected value $E(|col|) = \frac {{n}\choose{2}}{m}$. For this I want to use Chernoff, 
$|col|=\sum{i=1}^{n}$.

But what I can not understand are the given indicator RVs $I_{i}$ mutually independent or not?

Comment: I think it depends on how you handle collisions.

Comment: @Christian Sievers I just increase counter and make slot used.

Comment: You use the next slot, so that after $i$ insertions, whether there were collisions or not, $i$ slots are used? Then it seems to me that the $i+1$st entry should have collision probability $i/m$ and be independent from earlier collisions.